Old laptop works fine. New laptop, new Miktex and Texstudio install. Trying to Build &View from local Google Drive but Orcid is giving error message
Old laptop install builds and views fine, but with new laptop on same .tex file (whole file structure is fine) I get error message.  Is there something wrong with my settings? MiKTeX says no more updates available. This is the line for \usepackage:
\usepackage{orcidlink}%
%%%%

The error message I am getting is:
orcidlink.sty: error: 67: Command \orcidlogo already defined. }}{}}
PaperTitle.tex: error: 153: Package pdftex.def Error: File `Orcidlogo-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Clicking on the error message takes me orcidlink.sty

Old package says Packaged on 1/7/2024 and new one says Packaged on 6/29/2024. Could this be it?

Going to answer my own question and leave this here for anybody else.  I copied over the orcidlink.sty from my old laptop into the same place the new one was at (renamed it) and it will now build and view fine.  I will submit a bug report to the author if I can.
